# Python script in QGIS suddenly won't work

Tags: pyqgis

We use QGIS in our office for different purpose, one of which is to visualize photos we did on field trips. Since applying the Import algorithm every single time for every folder is tiresome, I wrote a small script, which nonetheless took all of my modest programming (=Python) skills (I know the implementation is clumsy). At first it seemed to work well, but after I finalized it over the weekend, it suddenly stopped working. Even worse: Even trying to produce a simple layer containing geotagged photos using the editor didn't work anymore.
I think there is an issue with running it from the editor istead of running it in the Python shell

```py
import qgis
import processing
import os
# Foto-Import Tool.

#Zwischen '' den jeweiligen Pfad angegeben.
pfad = 'W:\QGIS\Testdorf\Fotos\_Fotos/'


dir=[]
fotodir=[]
zwischendir=[]
fotolayer='/Fotolayer'
a = 'Drohne'
b = 'Bodenfotos'
format = '.shp' 

#Creates a list of Folders
p=os.listdir(pfad)


#This section creates paths. 3 lists are used, whereby "fotodir" is the final list containing the folders from which the vector layer is created.

###First level
for i in p:
    if i == a or i == b and os.path.isdir(pfad+'/'+i):
        fotodir.append(pfad+'/'+i)
    else:
        if os.path.isdir(pfad+'/'+i):
            dir.append(pfad+'/'+i)

###Second level.
for i in dir:
    m=os.listdir(i)
    for u in m:
        ###for diagnostic purpose
        #print(u)
        if u == a or u == b:
            fotodir.append(i+'/'+u)
        else:
            zwischendir.append(i+'/'+u)

###Third level.

for i in zwischendir:
    if os.path.isdir(i):
        m=os.listdir(i)
        for u in m:
            if u == a or u == b:
                fotodir.append(i+'/'+u)

###Checks if the respective folder "Fotolayer" already exists and creates it if it doesn't.
for i in fotodir:
    isExist = os.path.exists(i+fotolayer)
    if isExist == False:
        os.mkdir(i+fotolayer)
    else:
        continue        

for i in fotodir:        
    if i[i.rfind('/')+1:len(i)]== a:
        print('d_'+i[(i[0:i.rfind('/')-len(i)].rfind('/'))+1:i.rfind('/')-len(i)]+' - erkannt')   
    else:
        print('b_'+i[(i[0:i.rfind('/')-len(i)].rfind('/'))+1:i.rfind('/')-len(i)]+' - erkannt')


###Creates the layers.
counter = 0
for i in fotodir:
    if i[i.rfind('/')+1:len(i)]== a:
        output = i + fotolayer + '/' + 'd_'+i[(i[0:i.rfind('/')-len(i)].rfind('/'))+1:i.rfind('/')-len(i)]+format
    else:
        output = i + fotolayer + '/' + 'b_'+i[(i[0:i.rfind('/')-len(i)].rfind('/'))+1:i.rfind('/')-len(i)]+format

    processing.runAndLoadResults('native:importphotos', {'FOLDER': i, 'RECURSIVE': 0, 'OUTPUT': output, 'INVALID': 'memory'})
    counter = counter +1
    print(output + ' - Erstellt/Aktualisiert')

print('Herzlichen Glückwunsch! '+str(counter) + ' Layer erstellt!')
```

Instead of the desired outcome, I am confronted with this output:

```
b_Badesee - erkannt
d_Badesee - erkannt
b_Leising - erkannt
d_Leising - erkannt
d_Gewerbegebiet - erkannt
d_Nord - erkannt
b_Süd - erkannt
d_Süd - erkannt
b_Unterfeld - erkannt
b_West - erkannt
d_West - erkannt
b_Zentrum - erkannt
d_Zentrum - erkannt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 90, in <module>
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 138, in runAndLoadResults
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(alg, parameters=parameters, onFinish=handleAlgorithmResults, feedback=feedback, context=context)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 183, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Fehler bei der Ausführung des Algorithmus.
```

It also won't work when simplified.

```py
import qgis
import processing
import os
processing.runAndLoadResults('native:importphotos', {'FOLDER': 'W:\QGIS\Wurmschachen\Fotos\_Fotos3/Badesee', 'RECURSIVE': 0, 'OUTPUT': 'W:\QGIS\Wurmschachen\Fotos\_Fotos3/Badesee/Fotolayer', 'INVALID': 'memory'})
```

produces:

```
exec(open('C:/Users/AF391~1.PIR/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpsd12_3gq.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 138, in runAndLoadResults
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(alg, parameters=parameters, onFinish=handleAlgorithmResults, feedback=feedback, context=context)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 183, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Fehler bei der Ausführung des Algorithmus.
```

Interestingly I am sure it ran through (even using a more simple version of the for-loop) recently.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a string containing backslashes \. This is an escape character in Python which means the interpreter is trying to read the character immediately afterwards as a special character (like `\n` for new line). Either escape your backslashes by making them double (`\\ `) or use the `r` notation for your string (`pfad = r'W:\QGIS\Testdorf\Fotos\_Fotos/'`). That may clear up your error, not sure.

Comment: You are also mixing forward slashes "/" and backslash "\" in the path delimeter.

Comment: True, but that used to work on friday. Also, using os.listdir(), I was alawys able to print() the respective files.
I tried it nonetheless, first replacing all backslashes with forward slashes - still the same error message and then went on with double backslashes, just to get the same message.

Comment: In general everything works fine, but
processing.run("native:importphotos", {'FOLDER': i, 'RECURSIVE': 0, 'OUTPUT': output, 'INVALID': 'memory'})
produces an error.
The list of modules imported at the start is growing, I know added:
import qgis.analysis
import qgis.core
import processing
import os

Comment: Running python.exe in qgis/apps/python37 I can reproduce the unsatisfactory results, however, just running "from qgis import processing", "from qgis.core import processing" and so on produces "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'".
Searching for a solution I came across the issue of the "path". sys.path returns a list of python-related folders inside the qgis program folder.
As noted above, sorry for being clumsy, I have no experience at all, I started with this with the simple motivation of freeing up time consumed by clicking around for hours.